# Effect size for interaction in Mixed model with R

Tags: r, size, lme4, effect, interaction

I am testing a mixed model with 2 categorical predictors (with 2 levels both).
I would like to know the effect size of the 2 categorical predictors and the interaction.

I'm using lmer package

How can I obtain these results?

Comment: You may want to give an example of what your code looks like (for the models)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with R.squaredLR function in the MuMinin package from CRAN. You take your experimental model and the null and feed them both in. See page 55 of the  doc here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MuMIn/MuMIn.pdf.